# How to show only columns that have certain values

Tags: excel, vba

Okay, I am completely new at this, so sorry for insulting anyone with what I suspect is a simple question. However, I have searched and attempted things for days and can't crack the nut - I just can't seem to get something to do all of the things I want.

Here goes:
I have a worksheet with values that change weekly. The number of rows and columns change as well. However, columns A, B, and C will always have date, name and location data and therefore must be preserved. The values in the columns from D onward include only the numbers 0, 1, 2, or 3.

I need to copy the columns to a second worksheet and then delete all of the columns from D onward that do not have a 2 or a 3 in them. In other words, I need to always keep columns A, B, and C, and also keep any column (and all of its data) if a 2 or 3 shows up anywhere in the column.

Alternately, I bet it would be quicker to cherry pick the first three columns, as well as any other columns that have a 2 or 3 in them, and then paste them to the second worksheet. However, I've read about using Union, which seems like the way to go, but it's way over my head.

Thanks in advance for any solutions.

Comment: What sort of worksheet? [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), or a spreadsheet?

Comment: Thanks. This is a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the relevance of `Union` so I hope I have not misunderstood your requirement.

The first task is to determine the last row and column.  There are a variety of techniques for finding the last row or column; none of which work in every situation.  I believe `SpecialCells` is the most suitable in this case.

When I am unsure how to achieve some objective, I break it into little tasks, code task 1 and use `Debug.Print` to output diagnostic information to the Immediate Window.  When I have got task 1 working, I add the code for task 2 together with new diagnostic information.  So my first macro, `Demo1` just outputs the last row and column.  Try placing values to the left or below any existing values to see what the macro outputs.

Note: I say little about the statements I am using.  In general it is easy to look up a statement once you know it exists.  Come back with questions if necessary but please try your own investigation first.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Demo1()

  Dim ColLast As Long
  Dim RowLast As Long

  ' Replace "Source" with the name of your worksheet
  With Worksheets("Source")

    ColLast = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    RowLast = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

  End With

  Debug.Print "Last column " & ColLast
  Debug.Print "Last row " & RowLast
  ' Note Cells(RowLast, ColLast) does not have to contain a value.

End Sub
```

The next task is to identify the columns to delete.  I use the worksheet function `CountIf` to count the number of 2s and 3s in each column starting from column 4 which is column "D".

```
Sub Demo2()

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColLast As Long
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowLast As Long

  With Worksheets("Source")

    ColLast = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    RowLast = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For ColCrnt = 4 To ColLast
      Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, ColCrnt), .Cells(RowLast, ColCrnt))
      Debug.Print ColCrnt;
      Debug.Print "  Num 2s=" & WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, 2);
      Debug.Print "  Num 3s=" & WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, 3)
    Next

  End With

End Sub
```

The final task is to delete the columns without 2s and 3s.  For `Demo2` I used a For-Loop.  The trouble with a For-Loop is you cannot change the End Value within the loop and we will need to do that as we delete columns. So for `Demo3`, I have to use a Do-Loop.

```
Sub Demo3()

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColLast As Long
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowLast As Long

  With Worksheets("Source")

    ColLast = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    RowLast = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    ColCrnt = 4
    Do While ColCrnt <= ColLast
      Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, ColCrnt), .Cells(RowLast, ColCrnt))
      If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, 2) + _
         WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, 3) > 0 Then
        ' This column contains a 2 or a 3.  Do not delete column.
        ' Advance to next column
        ColCrnt = ColCrnt + 1
      Else
        ' This column does not contain a 2 or 3.  Delete column.
        .Columns(ColCrnt).EntireColumn.Delete
        ' Reduce ColLast to allow for deletion.
        ColLast = ColLast - 1
      End If
    Loop

  End With

End Sub
```

Hope the above helps.

Comment: Hi Tony, Thanks for the code, it works perfectly. Sorry it took so long to respond.